# LINQ Query - How to parameterize a select distinct query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I am missing when trying to parameterize a "Select" with "Distinct" query.

This is a sample of the code I have repeated multiple times with different items to select.

```
    private void getCustomerCodeList(ObservableCollection<Model> FilteredData)
    {
        var distCustomerCode = FilteredData.Select(i => new { i.CustomerCode, i.FamilyName }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.FamilyName).ToList();

        DistinctCustomerCodeList.Clear();

        foreach (var item in distCustomerCode)
        {
            DistinctCustomerCodeList.Add(new Model() { CustomerCode = item.CustomerCode, FamilyName = item.FamilyName });

        }

    }
```

I am trying to convert this into one method where I can pass in the "Select" and the "Orderby" as parameters. The code below is as far as I was able to get, and it works fine if I pass in a lambda with one property, but errors as soon as I try to add a second.

```
        public void getDistinct<TKey>(ObservableCollection<Model> FilteredData, Func<Model, TKey> myDistinctProperty, Func<TKey, TKey> mySortingProperty)
    {


        var distinct = FilteredData.Select(myDistinctProperty).Distinct().OrderBy(mySortingProperty).ToList();

        DistinctCustomerCodeList.Clear();

        foreach (var item in distinct )
        {

            DistinctCustomerCodeList.Add(new Model() { CustomerCode = item.ToString() });
        }
    }
```

If I call this method:

```
getDistinct<string>(FilteredData, x => x.CustomerCode, x => x);
```

it works fine
but if I try:

```
getDistinct<string>(FilteredData, i => new { i.CustomerCode, i.FamilyName }, x => x.FamilyName)
```

it errors.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me.

Thanks.

**Update-**

Here is the error message I am receiving.

'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.OrderBy<Model, string>(ParallelQuery, Func<Model, string>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery'

I made the changes based on the clarification that **nalpnir** provided and here is what my updated code looks like.

```
       public void getDistinct<TKey>(ObservableCollection<Model> FilteredData, Func<Model, TKey> myDistinctProperty, Func<Model, string> mySortingProperty)
    {


        var distinct= FilteredData.Select(myDistinctProperty).Distinct().OrderBy(mySortingProperty).ToList();
        DistinctCustomerCodeList.Clear();
        foreach (var item in distinct)
        {

            DistinctCustomerCodeList.Add(new Model() { CustomerCode = item.ToString() });
        }
    }
```

This portion has the error provided above (FilteredData.Select(myDistinctProperty).Distinct())

and here is the updated method call:

```
getDistinct<Model>(FilteredData, i => new Model { FamilyName = i.FamilyName, CustomerCode = i.CustomerCode }, x => x.CustomerCode);
```

Update 2 -

Thank you all for your feedback.
I ended up using the answer from **JeremyLakeman**, as it fit best in the project I am working on.

The answer from **nalpnir** is awesome and I will try to implement it in the future.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry for venting but I will never understand why people will post a question and say "it errors" and not tell us what the actual error is!  Can you please add that?  Also, see [ask]. Will check back in a while to see if I can help.

Comment: @JohnWu, sorry for leaving that out.  Here is the error message I was receiving.  'IEnumerable<TKey>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.OrderBy<Model, string>(ParallelQuery<Model>, Func<Model, string>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<Model>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example turned each instance of Model into an anonymous type, then later back into a Model again. Instead, the generic distinct method should create a new Model with only the requested fields.

```cs
public void getDistinct<TOrder>(ObservableCollection<Model> FilteredData, Func<Model, Model> distinct, Func<Model, TOrder> sort)
    {
        var distinct = FilteredData.Select(distinct).Distinct().OrderBy(sort).ToList();

        DistinctCustomerCodeList.Clear();
        DistinctCustomerCodeList.AddRange(distinct);
    }
```

Then this should work, with the compiler able to infer the generic types;

```cs
getDistinct(FilteredData, i => new Model{ i.CustomerCode, i.FamilyName }, x => x.FamilyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple, the LINQ you are doing is wrong, for 2 reasons but the same reason itself:

- Your TKey is set as a string, so when you say new { i.CustomerCode, i.FamilyName } it doesnt know how to go from that expression to a string.
- The same occurs in the case of the sorting, x is of type String, and x doesnt know what x.CustomerName is.

What you should use is the Model as TKey, like this:

```
getDistinct<Model>(list, i => new Model { FamilyName = i.FamilyName, CustomerCode = i.CustomerCode }, x => x.CustomerCode);
```

**UPDATE:**
Since i noticed it didnt do what you wanted to do, which is to be able to get it without repetitions, I changed a bit the idea so you can get around it, and even made it more generic so you can implement it with any class you want, as long as you make a few changes which i ll explain

```
public static List<T> getDistinct<T, TKey>(ObservableCollection<T> FilteredData, Func<T, TKey> myDistinctProperty, Func<T, string> mySortingProperty)
    where T:Model, new()
{
    var DistinctCustomerCodeList = new List<T>();

    var distinct = FilteredData.GroupBy(myDistinctProperty).Select(x => x.First()).OrderBy(mySortingProperty).ToList();

    foreach (var item in distinct)
    {
        DistinctCustomerCodeList.Add(new T() { CustomerCode = item.CustomerCode, FamilyName = item.FamilyName });
    }

    return DistinctCustomerCodeList;
}
```

As you see now you have 2 Generics, One is T which i restricted to be of type Model, and the other one is another type whichever you want in this particular case it will accept `new { x.CustomerCode, x.FamilyName }` . I ll give you a link to a .Net fiddle so you know can see a demo

Demo: [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z0Fqpo)

You can toy with it. Basically whichever class you replace model for will work as long as you change the output of the type T, and change the Add inside the foreach. Inherited members of Model will also work so lets say for example you implement the following:

```
public class ModelExtended:Model
{
    public int NewProp { get; set; }
}
```

And also changed the ObservableCollection To ObservableCollection will also work because they share some properties

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I updated the code and it is now accepting multiple criteria.  However in the actual getDistinct method I am still getting the error  IEnumerable<TKey>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.OrderBy<Model, string>(ParallelQuery<Model>, Func<Model, string>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<Model>'.  Not sure why it does not recognize the orderby extension.

Comment: I can make your code work, but even with your first code the distinct isnt working, are you sure this code is correct? i assumed the basic worked to be hones

Answer (score 0):

The `OrderBy()` is expecting a generic type `TKey` but the parameter `mySortingProperty` is explicitly referencing `Model`. Update the parameter in your method definition as follows:

```
public void getDistinct<TKey>(ObservableCollection<Model> FilteredData, Func<Model, TKey> myDistinctProperty, Func<TKey, string> mySortingProperty)
```